# List of filenames to sqlite with Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to populate an sqlite3 database with a list of filenames from a directory using Python. I'm not sure why this is not working:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect( "databasefile.db" )
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS filenames (filename TEXT)')
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith(".ext"):
            cur.executemany('INSERT INTO filenames (filename) VALUES (?)', (filename))
            conn.commit()
```

I'd like it to produce this in the database file:

```
   Column
1  1st.ext
2  2nd.ext
3  3rd.ext
```

But instead it results in this:

```
   Column
1  1
2  r
3  s
4  t
5  .
6  e
7  x
8  t
9  2
10 n
11 d
12 .

etc.
```

Could anyone help me understand where I'm going wrong?

**EDIT:** Thank you, I didn't realize iterating over a string gives the individual characters. Added the comma to make 'filename' a tuple and resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you don't need to use executemany, since you're not actually doing more than one insert at a time.  Secondly, change `(filename)` to `(filename,)`.  Both strings and tuples support the iterator protocol, and without that comma, the executemany function is interpreting the variable `filename` as the thing to iterate over.  When you iterate over a string, you get individual characters.

The other thing you thing you might do is as follows:

```
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
    cur.executemany("INSERT INTO filenames (filename) VALUES (?)",
                    [(filename,) for filename in filenames if filename.endswith(".ext")])
    conn.commit()
```

Now you're actually taking advantage of executemany, and generally, fewer jaunts off to your database is better.

Comment: aaargh... you beat me to the answer by 14 seconds!

Answer (score 2):

I think your `filename` variable isn't a tuple, i think sqlite is considering it a string. To make a tuple, don't forget to put a trailing coma:

```
(filename,)
```

Remember, it's **commas** that make a tuple, not brackets!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
   if filename.endswith(".ext"):
       cur.executemany('INSERT INTO filenames (filename) VALUES (?)', filename)
```

Your problem is definitely that you are iterating over a string somewhere.

In a normal python IDE you can replicate this as follows:

```
>>> s = "my string"
>>> for x in s: print x
... 
m
y

s
t
r
i
n
g
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because `executemany` expects a *list* of items to execute. In your script, you have the line:

```
cur.executemany('INSERT INTO filenames (filename) VALUES (?)', (filename))
```

This simplifies down to:

```
cur.executemany('INSERT INTO filenames (filename) VALUES (?)', filename)
```

And then `executemany` interprets your filename as a list of single characters.

To fix it, you could turn your expression into a tuple:

```
cur.executemany('INSERT INTO filenames (filename) VALUES (?)', (filename,))
```

...or just do it all at once:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect( "databasefile.db" )
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS filenames (filename TEXT)')
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
    allowedFilenames = [f for f in filenames if f.endswith(".ext")]
    cur.executemany('INSERT INTO filenames (filename) VALUES (?)', allowedFilenames)
    conn.commit()
```